# Stop running the code after 15 seconds

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to write something to stop running the code after 15 seconds of running.

I don't want `While` loop or any kind of loop to be used and would like to use IF-ELSE conditions instead as it would make it easier for me in my code.

The part of code I want to stop being executed after 15 seconds is a FOR loop itself. Let's consider the below code for example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is test no. "+ i+ "\n");
}
```

How would you stop this loop after 15 seconds of running?

Comment: Use Timers in your code. Since your UIThread will remain hang for 15 seconds, I suggest you use backgroundworker for that

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I am a beginner with C#

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can assign DateTime variable before the loop having the current date and time, then in each loop iteration simply check if 15 seconds have passed:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds >= 15)
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("This is test no. "+ i+ "\n");
}
```

Update: while the above will usually work, it's not bullet proof and might fail on some edge cases (as Servy pointed out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218933/stop-running-the-code-after-15-seconds/13218959#comment18006572_13218959)), causing endless loop. Better practice would be using the `Stopwatch` class, which is part of *System.Diagnostics* namespace:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
{
    if (watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds >= 500)
        break;
    Console.WriteLine("This is test no. " + i + "\n");
}
watch.Stop();
```

Comment: @iSi I'm glad you had your issue resolved. [Please notice that you may mark a post as an answer to indicate that you have already solved the problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png). Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY nice, but please check before posting such comment. For example in this case the OP [has already accepted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187848/develop-a-packet-sniffer-to-tell-if-the-traffic-is-encrypted) before. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for providing the information. I've already checked before but it seemed that the answer was not accepted by the user even after posting the comment that indicates that your answer has solved the problem. I just wanted to make sure that everything is clear. Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY you are both right... I apologize as it was me not being really familiar with the forum here... I got the point and will always mark the right answer to my question... Have a great day...

Comment: @iSi you did well, no need to apologize. :-)

Comment: I have edited the post up on this page as I have another related question. Can you please help with this?

Comment: @iSi Since this question was already solved, it's recommended to ask another question using the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button located at the top right of this page. I hope you find an answer to your problem. Have a great day :)

Comment: @iSi Picrofo is correct, this might be related, but it's a different question. Please post it as new question and post link here. Can't promise anything, but I'll take a look. :)

Comment: Note that this code will crash and burn if you run it right around daylight savings time, and there can be other weird datetime issues as a result.  Using something like a `CancellationToken` will prevent such issues.

Comment: @Servy pretty extreme edge case but still, better be careful with those things. What about Stopwatch class? Think it's bullet proof?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, that'd take care of those problems.  It also will work for much smaller timespans, unlike DateTime.

Comment: @Servy thanks a lot for the help... BTW, here is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220294/stop-the-code-after-a-time-period

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting [my answer from my older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220294/stop-the-code-after-a-time-period/13220449#13220449) because it's more relevant here,

I think you need to measure time and stop the code after particular time say "15 seconds" ,`StopWatch` class can help you out.

```
// Create new stopwatch instance
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
// start stopwatch
stopwatch.Start();
// Stop the stopwatch
stopwatch.Stop();
// Write result
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",stopwatch.Elapsed);
// you can check for Elapsed property when its greater than 15 seconds 
//then stop the code
```

Elapsed property [returns TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) instance you would do something like this.

```
TimeSpan timeGone = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

To fit your scenario you can do something like this

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
TimeSpan timeGone;
// Use TimeSpan constructor to specify:
// ... Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
// ... The TimeSpan returned has those values.
TimeSpan RequiredTimeLine = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 15, 0);//set to 15 sec

While ( timeGone.Seconds < RequiredTimeLine.Seconds )
{
    stopwatch.Start();
    Start();
    timeGone = stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
Stop();//your method which will stop listening
```

**Some useful links**
[MSDN StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use below code, which would help to improve in performance.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```