# Stop the code after a time period

Tags: c#, sockets, datetime, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop running the code after 15 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218933/stop-running-the-code-after-15-seconds)

I am dealing with the code of a packet sniffer and I just want to make some modifications to it. Now I am trying to edit it so that once I start the program, it will only capture the packets for 15 seconds. Below is the part of code which intercepts the packets and as you can see I am dealing with Try/Catch/Throw and it works like a loop.

```
        public void Start() {
            if (m_Monitor == null)
            {

                try
                {

                    m_Monitor = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
                    m_Monitor.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IP, 0));
                    m_Monitor.IOControl(SIO_RCVALL, BitConverter.GetBytes((int)1), null);
                    m_Monitor.BeginReceive(m_Buffer, 0, m_Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnReceive), null);
                }
                catch
                {
                    m_Monitor = null;
                    throw new SocketException();
                }
            }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Stops listening on the specified interface.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop() {
        if (m_Monitor != null) {
            m_Monitor.Close();
            m_Monitor = null;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the socket intercepts an IP packet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ar">The asynchronous result.</param>
    /// 
    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar) {
            try
            {
                int received = m_Monitor.EndReceive(ar);
                try
                {
                    if (m_Monitor != null)
                    {
                        byte[] packet = new byte[received];
                        Array.Copy(Buffer, 0, packet, 0, received);
                        OnNewPacket(new Packet(packet));
                    }
                }
                catch { } // invalid packet; ignore
                m_Monitor.BeginReceive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnReceive), null);
            }
            catch
            {
                Stop();
            }
    }
```

How do you think I can modify this code so that it will be stopped once started after 15 seconds for instance? I have tried to use DateTime but it was not successfull and I couldn't kind of break this so-called loop.

Comment: well this is the extended question... I was asked to open another question...

Comment: @iSi Can you add some code which actually invokes `Start()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to measure time and stop the code after particular time say "15 seconds" ,`StopWatch` class can help you out.

```
// Create new stopwatch instance
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
// start stopwatch
stopwatch.Start();
// Stop the stopwatch
stopwatch.Stop();
// Write result
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",stopwatch.Elapsed);
// you can check for Elapsed property when its greater than 15 seconds 
//then stop the code
```

Elapsed property [returns TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) instance you would do something like this.

```
TimeSpan timeGone = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

To fit your scenario you can do something like this

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
TimeSpan timeGone;
// Use TimeSpan constructor to specify:
// ... Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
// ... The TimeSpan returned has those values.
TimeSpan RequiredTimeLine = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 15, 0);//set to 15 sec

While ( timeGone.Seconds < RequiredTimeLine.Seconds )
{
    stopwatch.Start();
    Start();
    timeGone = stopwatch.Elapsed;
}
Stop();//your method which will stop listening
```

**Some useful links**
[MSDN StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

**Note:**
Im' sure that i have given enough pointers that anyone can sort his problem through these basic approach ,kindly also check my comments for another approach.

Comment: @iSi I checked your code again but could'nt find what you posted here ,How about using events if time == 15 seconds raise `onStop` which can then call stop method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
```

and put the code after it. the code will be executed after the defined delay.

Good Luck

Comment: This is not my intention... this will only put the thread at sleep for 15 seconds and then will run it anyways...
I need to start the program and then let it run for 15 seconds and then have it stopped automatically...

Comment: @iSi check my suggestions ,and let me know

Comment: @dotNetSoldier I undetstand your point... You want me to write a condition to check the elapsed time and if it is exceeding 15 seconds, it will stop, right?
Well, I guess I have basic problems with the program as I am kind of lost between the Try/Catch pieces of the code and have no clue where to put your codes...

Comment: @iSi I'm smiling right now this happens when our thoughts are too much occupied due to the problem , I will try to give you some pointers..

Comment: @dotNetSoldier in the code that I am trying to edit, it just does not work... I edited it in 100 different ways but just does not work. do you think you can download this code from here and see if you can change it the way I want? (The code you get from this link will be a bit different from the one you see here though)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C

Comment: @iSi I didn't find the code in the question on the codeProject uploaded project.

Comment: @dotNetSoldier that is a different one actually but kind of similar... please check this new one on the MJsnifferForm.cs file...

Answer (score 0):

Given that your code uses a separate thread to do the actual work, you could set it up with this rather small amount of code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static YourSnifferClass sniffer = new YourSnifferClass();
        static AutoResetEvent done_event = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            sniffer.Start();

            // Wait for 15 seconds or until the handle is set (if you had a
            // Stopped event on your sniffer, you could set this wait handle
            // there: done_event.Set()
            done_event.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

            // stop the sniffer
            sniffer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.